# How to keep data once entered from "vlookup"

Tags: excel

I have a workbook that takes data from another workbook when both are open. I want to keep this data once inserted. Excel trying to get this data everytime when I open this workbook.
`=IFERROR(VLOOOKUP(C64;INDIRECT("'[" & $A$64 & "]" & "doc'!" & "A5:B8");2;FALSE);"")` This is the formula that I use.

Comment: If I understand correctly, your formula has to be evaluated only once. Thus, you could select all cells, press copy, and choose "paste as values". This would substitute the formula by its value.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try this:
Go to `advanced` tab of `excel options`.
Find [this heading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hkiP.png), untick `update links`, tick `save external values`.